# How to combine renderUI() and select from dplyr package?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I want to make the user of my app capable of displaying only the columns he wants to see. Because I do not know in advance what the names of columns are, I used "renderUI(selectizeInput..." and then used select from dplyr to pick up the wanted columns, but it seems it is not working. This is my code, and you can use any data with unknown in-advance column names.

```
# Ui.R
tabPanel(
  "Trend Presentation", uiOutput("choose_parameter"),
  withSpinner(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table1"))
)

# Server.R
output$choose_parameter <- renderUI({
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "Parmeter",
    label = "Choose Parameter",
    selected = "Xcoords",
    choices = names(getData()), multiple = F
  )
})

output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
  req(input$Parameter)
  req(getData())
  dt <- getData()
  dt %>% select(input$Parameter)
})
```

Comment: There is a typo: `inputId = "Parmeter",` should be `inputId = "Parameter",`

Comment: @TarJae hhhh that is true!!